How to Recover Data if Metadata partition was deleted
I accidentally wiped the metadata partition along with Dalvik/ART and Cache using TWRP and now I can't boot into the OS. Internal Storage and USB-OTG were excluded.
Is there any way to backup my data (files, photos...)? Either by somehow fixing what I did wrong and booting into the OS or just by connecting the phone to a PC and using adb or any other method?
When I boot into TWRP, the Internal Storage says 0mb and the TWRP built-in File Manager can see some folders and files but cannot access all of them. For example, it doesn't show anything inside the data folder, which is what I care about saving.
The phone is Poco F3 with Android 13 Custom ROM from Xiaomi.eu, rooted with Magisk v27 and alioth TWRP version 3.7.0-12-POCOF3-v7.9_A13, if that helps.
I know I can flash a new ROM and boot the phone. But right now, I don't care about fixing the phone, just about my data, and I just want to save it if possible in any way? It may even be encrypted, doesn't matter, as long as I can decrypt it later and access it.

No, not possible.

metadata partition contains the metadata encryption key. If I am not mistaken this means you have lost access to the key used to encrypt "directory layouts, file sizes, permissions, and creation/modification times" (not user data file content and file names). So theoretically you may be able to recover raw user data. However the user data decryption will most likely require the meta data to work.
